# Не корректно работает gettext на php

Tags: php, локализация, gettext

Есть код php в папке /var/www/html/:

```
// Задаем текущий язык проекта
putenv("LANG=ru_RU");
// Задаем текущую локаль (кодировку)
 setlocale (LC_ALL, "Russian");
// Указываем имя домена
$domain = 'flowchart';
// Задаем каталог домена, где содержатся переводы
bindtextdomain('flowchart', "/var/www/html/admin/modules/flowchart/i18n");
// Выбираем домен для работы
textdomain('flowchart');
echo gettext('test');
```

и верные файлы локализации в /var/www/html/admin/modules/flowchart/i18n
Данный пример выводит "test" хотя:

```
msgid "test"
msgstr "тест"
```

Но я скопировал папку /var/www/html/admin/modules/flowchart/i18n в папку /var/www/html/ и поменял bindtextdomain('flowchart', "/var/www/html/admin/modules/flowchart/i18n") на bindtextdomain('flowchart', "./i18n") тогда всё завелось и выдало "тест".

```
echo file_get_contents('/var/www/html/admin/modules/flowchart/i18n/ru_RU/LC_MESSAGES/flowchart.mo');
```

корректно выводит содержимое файла
В чем может быть проблема? Всё перепробывал: везде выставил chmod 7777, перезаписывал директорию и перекомпилировал .mo файл, пробовал разные вариации вызова локализации и т.д.
 Итог один: из корня работает, а из положенного места - нет.

Comment: так у вас домайн сдесь лежит `/var/www/html/admin/modules/flowchart/i18n/ru_RU/LC_MESSAGES/` а вы указываете на `/var/www/html/admin/modules/flowchart/i18n` в функции.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно было перезапустить воркер дергающий php. В моём случае apache
gettext агрессивно кеширует записи.

Answer (score 1):

Вроде бы все правильно указываете. А что, если так указать?

```
bindtextdomain($domain, './admin/modules/flowchart/i18n')
```

В случае с `gettext` сильно помогает вывод на экран результатов каждой команды (`setlocale`, `bindtextdomain` и т.п.), и чтение документации по возвращаемым результатам, т.к. если `setlocale` вам вернет `false`, то дальнейшие команды уже просто бесполезны.

Comment: Выводит(команда | результат):  


putenv("LANG=ru_RU") | 1  


setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian") | Russian  


bindtextdomain($domain, './admin/modules/flowchart/i18n') | /var/www/html/admin/modules/flowchart/i18n  


textdomain('$domain') | flowchart  


gettext('test') | test

Comment: Если скрипт работает под php-fpm, то попробуйте его перезапустить.

Comment: Нет, всё работает через Апач

Comment: Передернул апач - завелось! Видимо gettext агрессивно кеширует записи.